# subfloats not processed well with Sciposter

Tags: subfloats, sciposter

I am making a poster and I saw that sciposter is a very good poster class with the ability to process eps figures. Also I found that sciposter can handle `\psfrag` commands used to add labels on figures. I require this feature in my work. However I am having trouble to include subfigures as I normally do in a normal article class document. The example in the package sciposter comes with an example showing how to include subfigures, but I still want to use the subfig package as I normally do. Here is a minimal code:

```
\documentclass{sciposter}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{captionskip=15pt}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{psfrag}

\title{Generalized Pattern Spectra Sensitive to Spatial Information}

\author{Michael H. F. Wilkinson}

\institute{Institute for Mathematics and Computing Science,\\
       University of Groningen\\}

\email{michael@cs.rug.nl}  % shows author email address below institute

\begin{document}

\conference{{\bf ICPR 2002}, 16th International Conference on Pattern
Recognition, 11-15 August 2002, Qu\'ebec City, Canada}

\maketitle

%%% Begin of Multicols-Enviroment
\begin{multicols}{3}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering{
\subfloat[Good stiffness ratio $\overline{k}=0.2$]{
     \label{fig:subfig:first figure}
      \input{k02bb.tex}
  \includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]
  {k02bb.eps}}
\hfill
\subfloat[Bad stiffness ratio $\overline{k}=0.3$]{
     \label{fig:subfig:second figure}
     \input{k02bb.tex}
  \includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]
  {k02bb.eps}}
   \caption{Test figure}
     \label{fig:stiffgoodbad}}
\end{figure}


\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

The above file is adapted from the example file sciposter-example.tex that comes with the package. The only difference is that I am using `\subfloat` from the subfig package and that my figures are each in two files: 1 eps for the drawing and 1 tex files for the labels. This is how I normally do it when using Matlab and Laprint. On compiling the above I get the error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: \subfloat outside float.

l.50 \subfloat
              [Good stiffness ratio $\overline{k}=0.2$]{
?
```

I don't get this error with `\subfloat` when using the normal article or book class. What am I doing wrong here and why does it not work with sciposter?

Update: The files k02bb.tex and k02bb.eps can be downloaded from here:

***I've closed the link***. Contact me if you want the files.

There is an additional tex file: testforfigure.tex that is for a normal article class to test if combination of k02bb.tex and k02bb.eps works.

Even if we take away the two lines  \input{k02bb.tex} in the code that I put above, I still get the same error message. It seems that Sciposter can't handle `\subfloat` well.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Can you build an example that doesn't depend on external files?

Comment: Thanks. The sciposter-example.tex included with the package works fine and figures are included. I also tested a figure with \psfrag commands and it works fine. \subfloat is giving problems. By external files, do you mean my figures?

Comment: @yCalleecharan: I've marked your inline code with backticks `\``.

Comment: @yCalleecharan: Graphics files are not the problem. They can be ignored with the »demo« option for the `graphicx` package. But there are others like `k02bb.tex` which we don't have.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt : Thanks. I didn't know how to do this.

Comment: @Thorsten Donig : Yes, you are right. I can create a very simple plot (a simple line) and put the tex file here. But then I will have to put the corresponding eps file also. Can I do it here...to put a picture or another file for people here to download?

Comment: have you tried to use the subcaption package that ships with the caption package? I found that it is more advanced that subfig. Also, do you really need floats in a poster, that doesn't seem right to me? A more minimal example would be good, my sciposter example folder has files with different file names...

Comment: @Martin H : Thanks. You are indeed right to say that floats are not needed in a poster. How to do it otherwise? Yes the figures in sciposter's example has different names. Now I am trying with my own files...that has eps and a separate tex file.

Comment: @Thorsten Donig : I have put a link from which the k02bb.tex and k0bb.eps can be downloaded. We can use the same figures in both subfigures.

Comment: I can compile your sample document http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15487093/sciposter.jpg. If your graphics are that simpel, why dont you create them with tikz or pgfplots?

Comment: @Martin H :Thanks. Do u mean that you can compile the code I put above with the k02bb.tex and k02bb.eps? No, my actual graphics are complicated. I just gave a sample file and I get the same problem to compile this simple figure.

Comment: @Martin H : You asked why not tikz or pgfplots? Well I have been using Laprint with Matlab for many years and it has worked fine for me and I use psfrag to replace the text labels. It is the first time that I'm using Sciposter and I am having trouble.

Comment: @Martin H :The compilation works fine with testforfigure.tex that is in my GMX share folder. But here I am using Sciposter and I would like to ask you if you could actually use my code of Sciposter and get your result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the sciposter document class provides its own `figure` code the subfig package does not recognize the `figure` as floating environment.

So using `\captionsetup{type=figure}` as first line of the figure which contains subfigures should make `\subfloat work`, i.e.

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\captionsetup{type=figure}% tell subfig package that this is a figure
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works very nicely indeed. 1 vote up also.