# AIP conference proceedings template - placing subfigures vertically

Tags: subfloats, documentclass-writing

I am using the AIP conference proceedings class file (aip-cp.cls) for writing a paper. I want to place two subfigures vertically, one below the other, using the subcaption package. The following is a code similar to what I had used :

```
\documentclass{aip-cp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}

\begin{document}
\title{Test}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{type=figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ScatteringAmplitude.png}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ScatteringAmplitude.png}
    \end{subfigure} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I used `\captionsetup` in the above code because aip-cp class defines its own figure environment, and therefore the subcaption package does not recognize the figure as a floating environment as explained in an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8903/subfloats-not-processed-well-with-sciposter).

The problem is that the two subfigures appear side by side despite of using `\\` or `\newline`. I do not face this problem when I use the article class however. I believe that the problem is in the aip-cp class, but as I am new to latex I don't know if it is possible to edit it to solve my problem.

The aip-cp class can be downloaded from [here](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/proceeding/aipcp/info/authors). I would appreciate if someone can go through the aip class file and let me know how to edit it. I am also happy with any alternate solution.

PS: I have also tried to use `\subfloat` from the subfig package, but the output was still the same.

Comment: To begin with, the class doesn't seem to be compatible with `caption`.

Comment: Your example does not compile, because it uses a nonstandard `\documentclass`.  Could you post a MWE?

Comment: @Lorehead Thanks for the quick reply. Did you download the class file from  the link I posted above?

Comment: I see it now.  No, I haven’t, and probably someone else here will be better at answering your question.  I might take a look later if nobody else gets to it.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for pointing it. I just used the `subfig` package instead, and I did not see any warning. But my problem is still not solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is definitely not compatible with `caption` (and so also `subcaption`). It also redefines the `figure` environment in such a way that fools `\subfloat` from `subfig` into thinking that it is not in a floating environment.

Here's a suggestion for making `subfig` work, but I'd not be surprised if the copy editor of your submission will not be happy with it.

```
\documentclass{aip-cp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{subfigures}
 {\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}\def\@captype{figure}\centering}
 {\end{minipage}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Test}

\begin{figure}

\begin{subfigures}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
\end{subfigures}

\caption{This is the caption}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]